# Iniciação com Arduino

Tags: arduino

Tenho conhecimentos em programação web e mobile.

Tenho interesse enorme em aprender Arduino e integrar minhas criações na placa à sistemas web e mobile.

A minha dúvida é:

Vale a pena mexer com Arduino?

E se, por exemplo, no Arduino eu criar algo associado à minha residência (luzes, temperatura...), o Arduino que comprei vai ser usado para somente isso?

Se eu quiser fazer outro projeto (novo), para outra finalidade, preciso de outro Arduino?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Primeiro ponto:** Não precisa de outro `Arduino` pra carregar outro código na placa, basta plugar ele na máquina e, no software que pode ser baixado gratuitamente na [web](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software), clicar no botãozinho de `->` para enviar o código para a placa

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Segundo ponto:** Sim vale a pena para quem está começando a aprender uma linguagem de baixo nível<s>(aquela linguagem que conversa diretamente com o hardware, sem necessitar de um `so` para interpretar os comandos)</s>

Mesmo para pegar alguns conceitos de elétrica(componentes) e mecânica e etc, abre as portas pra quem está com vontade de partir para sistemas embarcados.

Comment: qual a diferença de arduino e rasperypi?

Comment: @RafaelAcioly nunca tinha ouvido falar, mas pelo que procurei me informar, aparentemente se trata de um mini-computador(uma plaquinha de menores proporcoes, e logicamente com um poder de processamento menor, com tudo que e necessario onboard) integrado com um microcontrolador, com isso facilita em muito a vida de alguns desenvolvedores que "gostam" da interface habitual de SO's pra trabalhar com um microcontrolador integrado